# Приложение для стрима на YouTube и twitch.tv

Tags: c#, wpf, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте, хочу создать приложение для того, что бы стримить на YouTube и twitch.tv.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать подобное приложение?

Интересует:

- Библиотеки(*.dll)
- Примеры кода
- Литература

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте провёл бы исследование темы при помощи google, сформировал список возникших конкретных вопросов и опубликовал бы здесь те, на которые не получилось найти ответы

Comment: @FLCL , меня и интересует конкретно литература на эту тему и библиотеки. А примеры кода были бы для меня крайне приятным бонусом.

Comment: @FLCL , я уже долгое время ищу в сети информацию по поводу стрима, но так как тема эта достаточно необычная, информации немного... Даже для того что бы сформулировать более подробные вопросы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitch](http://dev.twitch.tv/)

[Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet)

[Twitch](https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api)

Все элементарно гуглится и все есть в сети..

Так же по словам `"youtube api"` | `"twitch api"` на [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=twitch%20api) достаточно много "видео-уроков", конечно же они не прям для профи разработки, но для приложения "для себя" достаточно.

Comment: Странно, как я не нашел этих ссылок... Вы меня очень выручили, спасибо большое!

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov, обновил ответ.